# Создание видеочата QT

Tags: c++, qt, видео

Для курсовой нужно написать видео чат.

Я получаю картинку с камеры через QCamera, вывожу в QCameraViewfinder.
Подскажите где найти информацию по передаче видеопотока/созданию видео чата.
Книги, видео, статьи, что угодно три дня ищу информацию и ничего адекватного

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можете использовать [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org)

Также для него существует плагин для [Qt5 QML](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/bindings/qt.html)